# Python mysql.connector: adding record with timestamp

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, timestamp

## BACKGROUND

This command successfully added 5 fields (all strings) to a table's record:

```
import mysql.connector
...
add_scan = ("INSERT INTO tblScanpoint "
               "(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 ) "
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
data_scan = ('AAAabc', 'AA', '4321', 'SEA', '3')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute(add_scan, data_scan)
cnx.commit()
...
```

The sixth field's datatype is TIMESTAMP.

## ERROR MESSAGE

Error from attempting to update all six fields:

```
>>> cursor.execute(add_scan, data_scan)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'when ) VALUES ('CCCabc', 'AA', '4321', 'SEA', '3', '2016-11-07 20:46:56.35')' at line 1
```

## TIMESTAMP UPLOAD DETAILS

These strings were modified to accomodate sixth TIMESTAMP field:

```
stamp = '2016-11-07 20:46:56.35'
add_scan = ("INSERT INTO scanpoint "
               "(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, when ) "
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
data_scan = ('CCCabc', 'AA', '4321', 'SEA', '3', stamp)
```

Is the error thrown because it is fed a string?   *Seeking corrective-action suggestions.  Clever examples are appreciated.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the issue `when` your column name which is a keyword/reserve-word. You need to escape it using backtique. See below

```
(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, when ) 
                      ^.... problematic column name
```

This should be escaped

```
(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, `when` )
```

Comment: Excellent catch: much appreciated.